# Did the Designers of Teotihucan have an advanced understanding of Acoustics?

Tags: mexico, cities, ancient-history

Teotihucan was one of the most impressively built and planned cities in ancient and world history. It is approximately 30 miles South of Mexico City and was founded around 200 BC/BCE-(though its preeminence dates from 150 BC/BCE to 750 AD/CE, around the same time as The Maya. However, it should be noted that the Maya were not the Original Founders of Teotihucan).  The city is comprised of nearly perfect geometric pyramidal structures, the most famous being the Pyramids of the Moon and Sun. Like the Maya, the Founders and later residents of Teotihucan were skilled Astronomers and Timekeepers,as well as brilliantly skilled Architects and Urban Planners.

However, the city of Teotihucan, (according to those who visit), is also said to have a uniquely all encompassing echo effect, especially when clapping-(both individually and in unison). Did the Ancient Teotihucan Urban Planners deliberately design an acoustically advanced city? If so, did these early Urban Planners in Teotihucan have a deep understanding and pioneering knowledge  regarding the mathematics of sound?-(similar to the Ancient Greeks and Romans).

Comment: Please cite the claim(s) about the echo effect and clarify why this constitutes an "advanced understanding".

Comment: Well, if you consider the time period when Teotihucan was designed-(over 1200 years ago), whereby much of the Americas-(the Maya being the notable exception), was comprised of tiny villages, as well as forested lands, the immensity of Teotihucan's size combined with its ability to create a uniquely sounding mass echo effect would have been the sign of a highly advanced civilization within the Americas-(and perhaps beyond).

Comment: The echo effect of Teotihucan would have been a sign of an advancement in acoustical engineering and the mathematics of sound when compared with most of their counterparts in the Americas-(again, the Maya being the exception), who, as far as we know, did not progress towards advancements in the refinement of sound and its relationship to urban planning and architecture. In other words, Teotihucan's architectural and engineering-(including its acoustical engineering) distinctiveness and uniqueness made it a more advanced society when compared with its peers and contemporaries.............

Comment: within the Americas and perhaps beyond.

Comment: Please do not respond in comments; edit the question. The question should stand alone.

Comment: Actually, I can point you to a spot in Tulsa where people [make similar claims](https://www.atlasobscura.com/places/the-center-of-the-universe) about acoustics. It also happens to be the origin point for Tulsa's coordinate system. Does that mean the Creek tribe who founded the settlement **also** had advanced knowledge of acoustics?

Comment: I am unable to comment on the history of the Creek Tribe.

Comment: Actually Teotihucan is 25 miles Northeast of Mexico City, not South of Mexico City.